# Como conectar Python com banco de dados MySQL?

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, python

Gostaria de saber como posso fazer uma conexão simples com MySQL através de um script Python.

Para eu fazer isso eu preciso instalar alguma biblioteca? Ou já existe algo que venha por padrão em Python (igual tem no PHP)?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Sim. Você precisa ter o MySQL instalado na sua máquina. Quando você já tiver instalado e configurado o MySQL, você instala a [API MySQL-python](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/).

[Exemplo](https://web.archive.org/web/20190507083632/http://wiki.infolink.com.br:80/Conex%C3%A3o_Python_com_banco_de_dados_MySQL):

Primeiro você importa os drivers

```
import MySQLdb # para o MySQL
```

E utiliza o seguinte código para fazer a conexão:

```
con = MySQLdb.connect(host="ServidorMysql", user="UsuarioMysql", passwd="SuaSenha", db="SeuDb")
con.select_db('banco de dados')
```

Esses são os parâmetros mais comuns. Se você instalou o servidor e não fez alterações, o seguinte pode usar:

```
con = MySQLdb.connect(user='UsuarioMysql', db='SeuDb')
```

Para obter uma transação (`cursor`):

```
cursor = con.cursor()
```

Para executar um comando SQL:

```
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO TABELA (CAMPO1, CAMPO2, CAMPO3) VALUES (?,?,?)', (valor1, valor2, valor3))
```

Você pode usar um `for` para inserir vários valores:

```
for i in xrange(10):
     c.execute("INSERT INTO teste VALUES (%s, 'teste%s')"%(i, i))
```

Para salvar as alterações:

```
con.commit()
```

Para obter o resultado:

```
rs = cursor.fetchone() # busca uma linha ou;
rs = cursor.fetchall() # busca todas as linhas ou;
rs = cursor.dictfetchall() # busca todas as linhas,
                           # cada linha tem um dicionário
                           # com os nomes dos campos
```

Script de exemplo:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: latin-1 -*-
# Importa o modulo de conexao com o mysql
import MySQLdb

# Gera a string de conexao ex.: seu host, seu usuario, sua senha e seu db
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="mysql.lhost03.w3br.com", user="lhost03", passwd="suasenha", db="seudb")
# Posiciona o cursor
cursor = db.cursor()
# Executa a consulta na tabela selecionada
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM seudb.suatabela")
# Conta o numero de linhas na tabela
numrows = int(cursor.rowcount)
# Obtendo resultados
print "--------------------------------------------------"
print "| ID  Campo                                      |"
print "--------------------------------------------------"
# Laço for para retornar os valores, ex.: row[0] primeira coluna, row[1] segunda coluna, row[2] terceira coluna, etc.
for row in cursor.fetchall():
   print " ",row[0]," ",row[1]
```

Essa não é a única API, existe também a [DB-API](http://isk.sourceforge.net/docs/python/pydbapi/).

Se não quiser usar API, você pode instalar o [MySQLdb](https://pypi.org/project/MySQL-python/), que ao contrário do php, no Python, apenas o driver SQLite é instalado por padrão.

Para Linux,você pode usar `sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb`.

Após a instalação:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",    # seu host
                     user="seuNome",      # seu user
                     passwd="senha",      # sua senha
                     db="SeuDB")          # nome do seu banco de dados

# Cria Cursor  
c = db.cursor()

# Executa o comando SQL
c.execute("SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE_NAME")

# Imprimir toda a primeira célula de todas as linhas
for l in c.fetchall():
    print l[0]

db.close()
```

Baseada nessa [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372885/how-do-i-connect-to-a-mysql-database-in-python/622308#622308) do stackoverflow em inglês.

Lembrando que o [Python não possui acesso nativo a bancos de dados SQL](https://wiki.python.org.br/BancosDeDadosSql) em sua biblioteca padrão, somente ao Berkley database engine(BDB), mas define uma API padrão que os drivers de acesso a esses bancos de dados devem seguir, assim qualquer que seja o banco de dados os procedimentos são parecidos.

Comment: Perfeito, depois de fazer os testes, pude finalmente, marcar como útil. Deu todo certinho!

Answer (score 12):

O próprio site [do MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/) possui uma área voltada para este assunto, mas irei tentar resumir um pouco.

Primeiro, você necessita do [Connector MySQL for Python](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/2.1.html).

Após a instalação do connector, basta importar para seu sistema. Um exemplo seria isso:

```
import mysql.connector

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='scott', password='tiger',
                              host='127.0.0.1',
                              database='employees')
cnx.close()
```

Para utilizar a conexão, basta fazer algo parecido com isso:

```
import datetime
import mysql.connector

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='scott', database='employees')
cursor = cnx.cursor()

query = ("SELECT first_name, last_name, hire_date FROM employees "
         "WHERE hire_date BETWEEN %s AND %s")

hire_start = datetime.date(1999, 1, 1)
hire_end = datetime.date(1999, 12, 31)

cursor.execute(query, (hire_start, hire_end))

for (first_name, last_name, hire_date) in cursor:
  print("{}, {} was hired on {:%d %b %Y}".format(
    last_name, first_name, hire_date))

cursor.close()
cnx.close()
```

Caso queira ver mais exemplos, você poderá obter na [documentação oficial do MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-examples.html).

Existem outras formas de fazer, o que é mostrado [nesta pergunta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/372885/4843158).

Comment: A sua resposta funcionou perfeitamente, cara. Só tive um pouco de dificuldades pra instalar, mas isso aí já é outra história.

Answer (score 5):

Apenas um adendo: Quem teve dificuldades de instalar a biblioteca Mysql Connector através do `virtualenv`, como eu tive, poderá usar o seguinte comando:

```
$ pip install mysql-connector-python-rf
```

Já a outra biblioteca citada, a MySQL-Python, eu precisei rodar os seguintes comandos:

```
$ easy_install -U distribute
$ pip install MySQL-Python
```