# Instalar o Mysql para usar com Python

Tags: mysql, python, python-3.x

Sou inciante no python e quero saber como instalar o mysql para armazenar informações do terminal.

Utilizo o wamp/mysql para desenvolver em php, é possível fazer alguma relação entre eles?(utilizar o mysql do wamp para python?)

Uso Windows 10 e python 3.4.4

Comment: O banco é o mesmo, não precisa fazer uma instalação nova o MySQL. Precisa ver as configurações do python. Relacionada: [Como conectar Python com Mysql?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/176521/91)

Comment: Obrigado! Vou prosseguir com seu link!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É necessário instalar a versão da biblioteca [PyMySQL](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL) no terminal python