# Como criar um código em python e conectar ele ao Mysql

Tags: python, mysql

Eae Galera, estou aprendendo a linguagem de banco de dados, porém eu ainda não sei tudo ao pé da letra então vim aqui pedir ajuda para vocês para saber como posso fazer isso. Eu sei que existe o sqlite3 no python porem eu quero usar o mysql, que no caso estou com o workbench no meu linux. Então eu quero tipo Criar um código no Python na qual o usuário executa o programa e entra e cadastra os funcionários da empresa ai esse programa salva em um banco de dados (será que tem como colocar o banco de dados como se fosse online ai o programa conecta ao banco e fica salvando ?) ai toda vez que ele entrar ele pega e pede a senha, até ai tudo bem eu já tenho noção de como fazer, mas meu problema e como eu crio o banco de dados no workbench e depois conecto ele no Python e depois faço o insert into dos dados. Outro ponto também que estou com duvida é tipo se tiver como eu colocar o banco de dados online como eu vou conectar o aplicativo nele e como eu faço alterações nele tipo ver que registrou, adicionar novas tabelas, apagar linha e etc...Me ajudem ai sou novo nisso preciso de dicas e ajudas por favor.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como conectar Python com Mysql?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/176521/como-conectar-python-com-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

Existem varias formas de fazer isso, sem conhecer o seu contexto é dificil dar uma resposta precisa. Vc vai usar algum framework para colocar o "aplicativo" no ar? Vc tem algum banco legado ou vai iniciar "from scrap"? nos dois casos vc pode usar o [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) ou o [Django,](https://www.djangoproject.com/) ambos utilizam a estrategia de mapeamento do banco de dados ([ORM](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mapeamento_objeto-relacional)), o flask utiliza o [sqlalchemy](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/), que voce pode usar mesmo que não utilize o flask, ja o Django utiliza um ORM próprio.

Se vc não for utilizar nenhum framework, e vai desenvolver com o python "puro", então com certeza a minha sugestão é o sqlalchemy.

Comment: O unico problema com django e que eu nao tenho ideia nem pra onde ir

Comment: Mas com django teria como eu fazer um programa completo em python e depois usar ele pra conectar o programa no banco de dados online ?

Comment: O dango é um framework todo feito em python, ou seja, é um conjunto de peças de software python que 'faz' para voce o que vc levaria meses para fazer sozinho. Sim vc pode conectar a maioria dos bancos, mas umas das coisas mais legais no django é deixa-lo gerenciar o banco, dessa forma vc definiria a estrutura do mesmo através do proprio django. Para começar eu ja te dei a dica do site, [faça esse tutorial completo.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/pt-br/1.11/intro/tutorial01/)

Comment: mas tem como eu fazer o programa ai eu faço o banco de dados(programa totalmente em python puro) ai eu hospedo o banco de dados deixando-o online e faço uma conexão entre o programa eo banco de dados ? se tiver como me explica como posso fazer ?

Comment: Ahahaha, vc quer que eu faça para voce? pesquise um pouco.